# How do I delete marked lines in SciTE?

Tags: scite

In Notepad++, it is possible to delete bookmarked lines by selecting *Search → Bookmark → Remove Bookmarked Lines*.

Is there a similar option in SciTE to remove marked lines in a document?

Answer (score 1):

In SciTe you choose from the Search menu "Select All Bookmarks" and then press Delete. That's it ...

Comment: By the way: the above method creates multiple cursors (one in each bookmarked line) you can then work with. To cancel this multiple cursor mode just click the mouse (tested on SciTE version: 5.1.6).